# Debian 8 High memory usage by rsyslogd (virtual not resident) on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, memory-leaks

After using Debian for awhile, I noticed that each rsyslogd thread is taking a lot of memory, 252MB Virtual Memory.

I read that virtual memory is allocated but not used, but regardless, that never has happened before:

[image: htop output]

The output of free -mh command:

[image]

How do I correct this issue (if it needs to be corrected)?

Comment: Video is no longer available.  This is an old question.  If you no longer have the video and the question has been overtaken by events, consider closing or deleting it.